# Ms Sql Trim comma , convert int , get data from another table

Tags: sql

I have varchar Id like below,

```
'1','2','3' etc..
```

I split as comma after that i convert Id to int

```
SELECT  FIRSAT_PERSONELLER_ID,
cast(LTRIM(C.value('n[1]','VARCHAR(50)')) as int )AS item1
FROM (SELECT *,
X = CAST('<myxml><nodes><n>' + REPLACE(FIRSAT_PERSONELLER_ID,',','</n></nodes><nodes> <n>') + 
'</n></nodes></myxml>' AS XML)
FROM FIRSATLAR 
)t
CROSS APPLY X.nodes('/myxml/nodes') Cols (C)
```

Result is like below:

```
item1:

1

2

3
```

i want to match above "item1" Id with my User Table.I tried below code however it did not work.I want to see User Names.

```
SELECT username
FROM UserTable
Where UserId=item1Id(İtem1Id does not appear)
```

Also i am not sure Id value is int or varchar.

Instead of above query , what i need to write ?

Answer (score 0):

tSQL would look like this:

```
SELECT username
FROM UserTable a
    join
    (SELECT  FIRSAT_PERSONELLER_ID,
            cast(LTRIM(C.value('n[1]','VARCHAR(50)')) as int )AS item1
            FROM (SELECT *,
            X = CAST('<myxml><nodes><n>' + REPLACE(FIRSAT_PERSONELLER_ID,',','</n></nodes><nodes> <n>') + 
            '</n></nodes></myxml>' AS XML)
            FROM FIRSATLAR 
            )t
            CROSS APPLY X.nodes('/myxml/nodes') Cols (C)
    ) b on a.UserId = b.item1
```

hope this helps.